# A couple of questions about the moduli space of annuli with some marked points on the boundary components

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces, riemann-surfaces, holomorphic-symplectic, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

I'm trying to work out an answer for my previous question and I'm stuck with the following issue:

In the paper [Deformations of Bordered Riemann surfaces and associahedral polytopes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.1676.pdf) by Devadoss, Heath and Vipismakul, in the example at the bottom of page 8 they are considering the moduli space $$\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{(0,2)(0,\langle 1,1,\rangle)}$$ which studies the configurations of an annulus with two boundary marked points, $1$ for each boundary component. They conclude that "it too is **not** a CW-complex, again due to a loop of weight two".

On the other hand, Abouzaid in his paper ["A geometric criterion for generating the Fukaya category"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.4593.pdf) , in appendix C.4 (page 38) claims that the compactified moduli space $$\overline{\mathcal{C}}^-_1$$ is a manifold with boundary (actually diffeomorphic to the interval $[0,\infty]$).
For reference, $\overline{\mathcal{C}}^-_1$ is the compactification of $\mathcal{C}^-_1$ which is the real line consisting of the annuli $\{z\in \Bbb C \mid 1 \leq |z| \leq r\}$ and marked points $\{1, -r\}$.

I'm sure I am missing something but in the first example we are dealing with a $2$-dim space, and in the second one with a segment.

> What are the additional condition in Abouzaid's moduli space that justify his model for the compactification? The only apparent difference between the two is that in $\mathcal{C}^-_1$ we are forcing a symmetry in the configurations. Does it mean $\mathcal{C}^-_1$ is the fixed point set of a certain $\Bbb Z_2$ action on $\mathcal{M}_{(0,2,\langle 1,1\rangle)}$ which happens to be a $1$-manifold?

My end-game is to prove that [this moduli space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377540/moduli-space-of-annuli-with-marked-points-satisfying-some-additional-symmetries) of annuli with an additional symmetry is a manifold (with corners), so I'm trying to understand how these spaces are built. This question is closely related with these two old questions: ([an old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377540/moduli-space-of-annuli-with-marked-points-satisfying-some-additional-symmetries) and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270047/deligne-mumford-compactification-of-moduli-space-of-annuli) on the compactification of the moduli space of annuli.)

Thanks for any sort of input/observations!